# How to override select all action? material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Material-Table allows for disabling certain rows from being selected, but when the user then presses select all it will highlight the disabled rows. Is there some way to have this functionality ignore rows that are disabled?

Code disabling the rows:

```
options={{
    selection: true,
    selectionProps: rowData => ({
        disabled: disableRow(rowData)
    })
}}
```

Image example of selecting disabled rows with select all:

[image: proving you can select disabled rows with select all checkbox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obvioulsy a bug.

For now, you can fix it by setting tableData.checked to false for the disabled rows in onSelectionChange. If the data is saved within this.state and you want to disabled all rows use this:

```
 onSelectionChange={(rows) => this.setState({data: rows.map(row => ({
    ...row,
    tableData:{
    ...row.tableData,
    checked: false
    }
    }))})}
```

If you have a function like `disableRow`, you can use this, to set the checked prop for the individual rows. This will let you control the selection.

You should open an issue to address the selection of disabled rows at material-table to fix this in the future.

Comment: Someone else already opened an issue for this and the developer asked for it to be posted on stack overflow.

Appreciate your help though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case (without using any `setState`):

```js
data={yourData.map(row => {
  row.tableData = {...row.tableData, disabled: disableRow(row)};
  return rowData;
})}
options={{
  selectionProps: row => ({disabled: row.tableData.disabled})
}}
```